# Ng-toggle, add to array,

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have a list of items, using `ng-repeat`. All of the items have an id which is accessbile like `{{item.id}}` when I toggle that specific item I want to push that items id to an array. I have tried numerous things but keep getting `undefined`.

This following is the current code i have tried. Thanks.

Template:

```
<ion-list>

    <ion-toggle toggle-class="toggleClass"
     ng-repeat="item in items"
     ng-model="item.checked"
     ng-change="updateTracker({{item.id}});"> <!--item.id didnt work either -->

    <span>{{item.name}}</span> <!--{{item.id}} this works -->

    </ion-toggle>

</ion-list>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.trackerList = [];
  console.log($scope.trackerList);
    $scope.addTrack = function() {
        $scope.trackerList.push(item.id);  //undefined
    };
    $scope.updateTracker = function(item) {
      console.log($scope.item.id)

    }
```

EDIT:

```
$scope.updateTracker = function(item) {
  console.log(item.id + "was added");
  $scope.trackerList.push(item.id); // only adds. would like to remove if toggle off
  console.log($scope.trackerList)
}
```

**THANK YOU developer033**

Comment: don't use `{{ .. }}` notation in the ng-event

Comment: @jeremy, some `ng-events` need the `{{}}`..

Comment: @developer033 when? which ones? ng-events parse the arguments at runtime: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L60

Comment: Well [**ngBindTemplate**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindTemplate) is one.

Comment: @developer033 how is this an event? i'm talking ng-event directives.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I was thinking you're talking about all `ng..`.

Comment: @developer033 certainly not. for example, ng-bind-template takes an `{{ expression }}` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngChange` directive expects an `expression`, so you should write it like this:

```
ng-change="updateTracker(item.id)"
```

**Edit:**

Since you're expecting an `item` in your `controller`, change it to:

```
ng-change="updateTracker(item)"

$scope.updateTracker = function(item) {
  console.log(item.id)
}
```

Comment: i tried that before. I keep getting error `ionic.bundle.js:26794 TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: i also tried item.name but I keep getting cant read property of id/name undefined... i know this are defined because they show up in the list

Comment: Well, are you sure that it has an `id`? It's almost impossible because you're passing the `item` as parameter.. are you sure that you did what I did above? Copy and paste in your code the 3 last lines..

Comment: `$scope.updateTracker = function(item) {
  console.log($scope.items.id)
}`I have tried both items.id and item.id

Comment: i was using scope still. that fixed it.. however if i toggle off, it still adds. how would i remove it if its toggled off?

Comment: just editted my comment regading toggle off and the addTrack function. ty

Comment: I can't see where you're calling the `addTrack function` in your `code`..

Comment: Well, I have never used the `Ionic`, but does it create any *property* called checked or something like that in your `objects`? If so you can just check it.. `if (item.checked) { $scope.trackerList.push(item); } else { $scope.trackerList.splice(trackerList.indexOf(item), 1); }`